# How to add my code to GitHub to create gh-pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, atom-editor

I have a *very newbie* question.. I made a website using HTML CSS and JS in Atom and I want to know how to upload everything to GitHub so I can make it into a gh-pages site.

I did it once before with a different website, also using Atom, GitHub and GitHub Desktop, but it was with a lot of hand-holding by my teacher. All the tutorials/ step-by-step instructions I can find are super confusing (or maybe my brain is fried). Could anyone help with straight-forward instructions? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

upload your code to a repository nameed "your username".github.io and then that should also be the url of the page too. it could take some to for it to start working tho.